# using .php with .css or some thing better?

Tags: facebook

I have a log in page for my web site. The log in file is "index.php" this will be the first page you come to when comming to my site. The rest of my site is HTML with a style.css file providing the look for my site. Now my questions is how do I get my index.php file too look like the rest of my web site?

Right now when you come to mydomain.com/index.php it is just a white page with a log in and password box. I would like my log in page to look like the rest of my web site. Can some one please refer me as how to do this?

I have other .php files that would also need to be linked with the .css such as register.php and so forth. thanks guys.

If there is a different/better method of doing what I need please feel free to chime in, I'm all ears at this point I've been trying to do this for 2 days.

Answer (score 1):

Like you would do in every other html page you will have to link the file the same way.
I guess that you have already seen that in every php file there is html code?
Just stay out of the php brackets

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
    </head>
    <body
<?php
```

> "php code in here"

```
?>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you don't find the usual html markup somewhere search for a include function in the php file.
Maybe the html header is in other php file and it is being called from there.

They would be included like this

```
include '_header.php';
```

Comment: thats the problem I'm having I have a _header.php and its what is confusing me.

Comment: every time I try and link pages together it dosnt work, I have even tried putting the link in the _header.php and still nothing

Comment: If you have that a_header.php open it and link the style sheet there.
And then every php file that calls that a_header.php will have the same styling.

Comment: Could you please write how you are linking the pages?

Comment: I used:  <head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
</head>

Comment: I put the above link in the _header.php but it still did not work.

Comment: what is in your _header.php?
Is it being included in the other php files?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>php-login-advanced</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
    <style type="text/css">
        /* just for the demo */
        body {
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            font-size: 12px;
            margin: 10px;
        }
        label {
            position: relative;
            vertical-align: middle;
            bottom: 1px;
        }
        input[type=text],
        input[type=password],
        input[type=submit],
        input[type=email] {
            display: block;

Comment: thats the first half and no I dont see it linknig it to any other pages.

Comment: I'm using a php-login advance from php-login.net

Comment: The other php files should be including it like this
    include '_header.php';
Also make sure that whatever is inside the <style type="text/css"><style>
Is not overriding whatever you have in your mystyle
Hope this can help you. Can't make this conversation longer

Comment: not sure if you replyed or not, said I had a reply but no new messages. lol

Comment: ;) lol I found the includes they said include _header at top oh php and include _footer at the bottom of the php file

Comment: There you go :) Just change the _header as you need to include the styling.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSS file, similar to how you use it in your HTML files. You can either post the CSS tag below your PHP code, or you can use an `echo "cssTagHere";` call within your PHP code.

If you're using a login page, though, are you maintaining that security with the rest of your site by using PHP on your other pages?

Comment: I thought I didn't have to use php on all the pages? I thought the only reason I needed to use it was so that I could have it linked to my database to save information.

Comment: You can always go to an html page if you know the url. Same with php pages. If you set it up right, though, php pages can allow or deny access to the page.

Comment: I down loaded a php login script with database .sql files. I then downloaded a web template for a web site, now I'm just trying to combine the 2.

Comment: Look up PHP sessioning if you want to know how to properly maintain session data across your entire site. Here's a basic example: http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php

Comment: If the login script was any good, it would set some session variables for you, which you can carry onto your other pages.

Comment: there supposed to be good, I down loaded the advanced version from php-login.net

Comment: If you have any further, specific questions, feel free to ask them here and we'll be happy to answer, if it hasn't been answered already. However, we can't and won't set your site up for you. There's plenty of documentation to use for that. :)